# Applying a rolling window to HP filter

Tags: r

Assuming I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("1990-03-01"), by = 'quarters', length.out=100)
Date<- as.yearqtr(Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
GDP <- runif(100, 500, 2000)
df <- data.frame(Date,GDP)
```

Usually in order to apply a hpfilter function, I would do this:

```
GDP <- xts(GDP[,-1], order.by=GDP[,1]) #Convert to xts
hpf <- hpfilter(GDP,freq=1600) #Apply the HP filter
GDP <- xts(cbind(hpf$x, hpf$trend, hpf$cycle), index(GDP))
colnames(GDP) <- c("GDP", "Trend", "Cycle")
```

However, I would now like to apply a rolling window of 20 quarters to my HP filter (i.e. Use 20 data points to filter out the trend) instead of using the whole series. I tried doing this:

```
rollapply(data=GDP, 20, hpfilter(GDP, freq=1600))
```

but got an error as hpfilter cannot be detected as a function. I am sure something is wrong somewhere and I am really new to R so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I manage to solve this by using a loop instead.

```
GDP<- xts(GDP[,-1], order.by=GDP[,1])
HPF <- merge(GDP, Trend=NA, Cycle=NA)
for (i in 20:length(GDP)){ 
hpf <- hpfilter(GDP[(i-19):i], freq=400000) 
temp <- xts(cbind(hpf$x, hpf$trend, hpf$cycle), index(GDP[(i-19):i])) 
HPF[i,] <- temp[20,]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ Binggg, there is an issue with your code, I don't how you ranned below part:

```
GDP <- xts(GDP[,-1], order.by=GDP[,1]) #Convert to xts
```

Since, if you run below

```
GDP <- runif(100, 500, 2000)
```

it generates as a vector. And in your above code GDP is considered as a data.frame, I think you might be referring to "df" instead of "GDP" as below:

```
GDP <- xts(df[,-1], order.by=df[,1]) #Convert to xts
```

Now, coming to your question of "apply a rolling window of 20 quarters to my HP filter", if you want to use HP Filter as function for "rollapply", then, you need to specify it as function, however, it is having an issue with xts format and works fine with data.frame as below.

```
library(mFilter)    
GDP_roll <- as.data.frame(rollapply(df[,2], 20, function(x) {hpfilter(df[,2], freq=1600)}))
```

Forgot to mention earlier that hpfilter function exists in library(mFilter), you need to call it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! You are right, the xts should be for the df & not vector. Anw, I tried your code and got an end result of 81 obs of 10 var, with each obs containing a list of all 100 output. I was expecting there to be only 80 output for trend & cycle since I am rolling 20 period and the first 20 obs should be empty? Was wondering if I am doing it correctly.
 
Hpf <- as.data.frame(rollapply(df[,2], 20, function(x) {hpfilter(df[,2], freq=1600)}))
GDP_roll <- as.data.frame(c(cbind(Hpf$x[1],Hpf$trend[1],Hpf$cycle[1])))
colnames(GDP_roll) <- c("GDP", "Trend", "Cycle")

Comment: Also, I tried running my original non-rolling hp filter and I am getting the same output as what I have using the rollapply function.